# Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start, Failed to run KubernetesPodOperator secret

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I'm running the quickstart for KubernetesPodOperator secret using the link below : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator

Code used below :

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator

# A Secret is an object that contains a small amount of sensitive data such as
# a password, a token, or a key. Such information might otherwise be put in a
# Pod specification or in an image; putting it in a Secret object allows for
# more control over how it is used, and reduces the risk of accidental
# exposure.

secret_env = secret.Secret(
    # Expose the secret as environment variable.
    deploy_type='env',
    # The name of the environment variable, since deploy_type is `env` rather
    # than `volume`.
    deploy_target='SQL_CONN',
    # Name of the Kubernetes Secret
    secret='airflow-secrets',
    # Key of a secret stored in this Secret object
    key='sql_alchemy_conn')
secret_volume = secret.Secret(
    'volume',
    # Path where we mount the secret as volume
    '/var/secrets/google',
    # Name of Kubernetes Secret
    'service-account',
    # Key in the form of service account file name
    'service-account.json')

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# If a Pod fails to launch, or has an error occur in the container, Airflow
# will show the task as failed, as well as contain all of the task logs
# required to debug.
with models.DAG(
        dag_id='composer_sample_kubernetes_pod',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:
    # Only name, namespace, image, and task_id are required to create a
    # KubernetesPodOperator. In Cloud Composer, currently the operator defaults
    # to using the config file found at `/home/airflow/composer_kube_config if
    # no `config_file` parameter is specified. By default it will contain the
    # credentials for Cloud Composer's Google Kubernetes Engine cluster that is
    # created upon environment creation.
  kubernetes_secret_vars_ex = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='ex-kube-secrets',
        name='ex-kube-secrets',
        namespace='default',
        image='python:3.6-stretch',
        cmds=["python","-c"],
        arguments=["print('hello world')"],
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        startup_timeout_seconds=300,
        # The secrets to pass to Pod, the Pod will fail to create if the
        # secrets you specify in a Secret object do not exist in Kubernetes.
        secrets=[secret_env, secret_volume],
        # env_vars allows you to specify environment variables for your
        # container to use. env_vars is templated.
        env_vars={
            'EXAMPLE_VAR': '/example/value',
            'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS': '/var/secrets/google/service-account.json'})
```

I have created successfully the secret using :

```
kubectl create secret generic airflow-secrets \
--from-literal sql_alchemy_conn=test_value
```

I am receiving this error :

```
> Reading remote log from gs://europe-west1-test-environme-5ad38518-bucket/logs/composer_kubernetes_pod/pod-ex-minimum/2020-11-08T10:29:28.767187+00:00/3.log.
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,764] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: composer_kubernetes_pod.pod-ex-minimum 2020-11-08T10:29:28.767187+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,817] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: composer_kubernetes_pod.pod-ex-minimum 2020-11-08T10:29:28.767187+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,818] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,818] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - Starting attempt 3 of 3
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,818] {taskinstance.py:882} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,894] {taskinstance.py:901} INFO - Executing <Task(KubernetesPodOperator): pod-ex-minimum> on 2020-11-08T10:29:28.767187+00:00
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,895] {base_task_runner.py:131} INFO - Running on host: airflow-worker-765557479f-zbzkm
[2020-11-09 10:57:38,895] {base_task_runner.py:132} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'composer_kubernetes_pod', 'pod-ex-minimum', '2020-11-08T10:29:28.767187+00:00', '--job_id', '54', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/kubernetes_secret3.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmp3qvpc1a6']
[2020-11-09 10:57:42,268] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:57:42,267] {configuration.py:618} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2020-11-09 10:57:42,365] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:57:42,364] {configuration.py:618} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2020-11-09 10:57:42,650] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:57:42,649] {default_celery.py:90} WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2020-11-09 10:57:42,651] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:57:42,651] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2020-11-09 10:57:42,652] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:57:42,651] {dagbag.py:397} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/kubernetes_secret3.py
[2020-11-09 10:57:43,393] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum Running <TaskInstance: composer_kubernetes_pod.pod-ex-minimum 2020-11-08T10:29:28.767187+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-765557479f-zbzkm
[2020-11-09 10:57:59,728] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:57:59,727] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:00,736] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:00,736] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:01,743] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:01,742] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:02,748] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:02,748] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:03,755] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:03,755] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:04,764] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:04,764] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:05,772] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:05,772] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:06,780] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:06,780] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:07,787] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:07,787] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:08,795] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:08,795] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:09,804] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:09,804] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:10,816] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:10,815] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:11,824] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:11,824] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:12,831] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:12,831] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:13,838] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:13,838] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:14,845] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:14,844] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:15,855] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:15,854] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:16,863] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:16,862] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:17,870] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:17,869] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:18,877] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:18,877] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:19,883] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:19,883] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:20,892] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:20,891] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:21,899] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:21,898] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:22,907] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:22,907] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:23,915] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:23,915] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:24,922] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:24,922] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:25,930] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:25,930] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:26,938] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:26,937] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:27,944] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:27,944] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:28,952] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:28,951] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:29,958] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:29,958] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:30,965] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:30,964] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:31,971] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:31,970] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:32,978] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:32,978] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:33,986] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:33,986] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:34,993] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:34,993] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:36,002] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:36,002] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:37,012] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:37,012] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:38,029] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:38,029] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:39,041] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:39,040] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:40,048] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:40,048] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:41,058] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:41,057] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:42,066] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:42,066] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:43,073] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:43,073] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:44,081] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:44,081] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:45,088] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:45,088] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:46,098] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:46,098] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:47,109] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:47,109] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:48,117] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:48,117] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:49,125] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:49,124] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:50,134] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:50,134] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:51,141] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:51,140] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:52,147] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:52,147] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:53,156] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:53,155] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:54,167] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:54,167] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:55,176] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:55,176] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:56,183] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:56,183] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:57,196] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:57,195] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:58,202] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:58,201] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:58:59,209] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:58:59,208] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:00,215] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:00,215] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:01,226] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:01,226] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:10,317] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:10,317] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:11,324] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:11,323] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:12,331] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:12,330] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:13,337] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:13,337] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:14,344] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:14,344] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:15,351] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:15,350] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:16,357] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:16,357] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:17,363] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:17,363] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:18,376] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:18,375] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:40,566] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:40,565] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:41,572] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:41,572] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:42,582] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:42,582] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:43,589] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:43,589] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,596] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:44,595] {pod_launcher.py:142} INFO - Event: pod-ex-minimum-02a096e7 had an event of type Pending
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,645] {taskinstance.py:1148} ERROR - Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 253, in execut
    get_logs=self.get_logs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 113, in run_po
    raise AirflowException("Pod took too long to start"
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod took too long to star

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred

Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 985, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 265, in execut
    raise AirflowException('Pod Launching failed: {error}'.format(error=ex)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to star
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,646] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:44,645] {taskinstance.py:1148} ERROR - Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,646] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 253, in execute
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     get_logs=self.get_logs)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 113, in run_pod
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {taskinstance.py:1205} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=composer_kubernetes_pod, task_id=pod-ex-minimum, execution_date=20201108T102928, start_date=20201109T105738, end_date=20201109T105944
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     raise AirflowException("Pod took too long to start")
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod took too long to start
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum 
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,648] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,648] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum 
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,648] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,648] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 985, in _run_raw_task
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,649] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,649] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 265, in execute
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,650] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     raise AirflowException('Pod Launching failed: {error}'.format(error=ex))
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,650] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,650] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum [2020-11-09 10:59:44,647] {taskinstance.py:1205} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=composer_kubernetes_pod, task_id=pod-ex-minimum, execution_date=20201108T102928, start_date=20201109T105738, end_date=20201109T105944
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,703] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,704] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 253, in execute
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,705] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     get_logs=self.get_logs)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,705] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 113, in run_pod
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,705] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     raise AirflowException("Pod took too long to start")
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,706] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod took too long to start
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,706] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum 
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,707] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,707] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum 
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,708] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,708] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,708] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,708] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,708] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     args.func(args)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,709] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 75, in wrapper
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,709] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,709] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 546, in run
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,709] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,709] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 466, in _run
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,709] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     pool=args.pool,
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,710] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,710] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,710] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 985, in _run_raw_task
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,710] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,710] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 265, in execute
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,710] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum     raise AirflowException('Pod Launching failed: {error}'.format(error=ex))
[2020-11-09 10:59:44,711] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 54: Subtask pod-ex-minimum airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start
```

**Do you have any insight ? Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.**

Comment: Did you try increasing your timeout?

Comment: I can't find an execution_timeout for the KubernetesPodOperator, I will try with the dagrun_timeout like below :


`with models.DAG(
        dag_id='composer_sample_kubernetes_pod',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:`

Comment: Try increasing your startup_timeout_seconds. The error indicates that the problem is on the time your POD gets to start

Comment: Thanks you for your help. Unfortunately, It's taking more time to fail with same error (I have set the timeout at 1200 instead of 300), am I missing a connection param ? I will try to put an explicit service account

Answer (score 7):

It was an issue regarding the `volume_secret`. I hadn't created it and it wasn't working cause it could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The above error will be generic and can't used for debug root cause. When you start your dag check the worker pod.Do kubectl describe pod  on worker pod .this will tell is any error in launching the worker pod of the task. Then you can check logs of same worker pod also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `startup_timeout_seconds` in KubernetesPodOperator()

it seems like airflow (composer) only waiting for 3 min and then throw ERROR
pod launching takes too long.

while pod is taking more time then that to creating node,

check in the k8 clutter if pod running.
and composer show this error again try to increase more time

```
KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                     affinity=affinity,
                     startup_timeout_seconds=900,
                     dag=dag
                     )
```

in this case

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator

# A Secret is an object that contains a small amount of sensitive data such as
# a password, a token, or a key. Such information might otherwise be put in a
# Pod specification or in an image; putting it in a Secret object allows for
# more control over how it is used, and reduces the risk of accidental
# exposure.

secret_env = secret.Secret(
    # Expose the secret as environment variable.
    deploy_type='env',
    # The name of the environment variable, since deploy_type is `env` rather
    # than `volume`.
    deploy_target='SQL_CONN',
    # Name of the Kubernetes Secret
    secret='airflow-secrets',
    # Key of a secret stored in this Secret object
    key='sql_alchemy_conn')
secret_volume = secret.Secret(
    'volume',
    # Path where we mount the secret as volume
    '/var/secrets/google',
    # Name of Kubernetes Secret
    'service-account',
    # Key in the form of service account file name
    'service-account.json')

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# If a Pod fails to launch, or has an error occur in the container, Airflow
# will show the task as failed, as well as contain all of the task logs
# required to debug.
with models.DAG(
        dag_id='composer_sample_kubernetes_pod',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:
    # Only name, namespace, image, and task_id are required to create a
    # KubernetesPodOperator. In Cloud Composer, currently the operator defaults
    # to using the config file found at `/home/airflow/composer_kube_config if
    # no `config_file` parameter is specified. By default it will contain the
    # credentials for Cloud Composer's Google Kubernetes Engine cluster that is
    # created upon environment creation.
  kubernetes_secret_vars_ex = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='ex-kube-secrets',
        name='ex-kube-secrets',
        namespace='default',
        image='python:3.6-stretch',
        cmds=["python","-c"],
        arguments=["print('hello world')"],
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        startup_timeout_seconds=1200,
        # The secrets to pass to Pod, the Pod will fail to create if the
        # secrets you specify in a Secret object do not exist in Kubernetes.
        secrets=[secret_env, secret_volume],
        # env_vars allows you to specify environment variables for your
        # container to use. env_vars is templated.
        env_vars={
            'EXAMPLE_VAR': '/example/value',
            'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS': '/var/secrets/google/service-account.json'})
```